# UNIX script to check for Multile files in same location created today

Tags: shell, unix

can you help me to built a unix script to check for Multiple files in same location  created today or not, I tried below code but this is checking for multiple location for single file.

```
enter  function WRITE_LOG(){
   echo "$(date) : $@" >> ${LOG_FILE}
```

}

```
function CHECK_FILE(){
 cd ${1}
 WRITE_LOG "Checking files in ${1}"
 ls -l | grep -q "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d").*RIG*"
 if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
 then
       WRITE_LOG "File created for today"
 else
       WRITE_LOG "File not created. please check"
 fi
 }

WRITE_LOG "Look for abc files" > $LOG_FILE
CHECK_FILE "/abc/zyx"
CHECK_FILE "/abc/QLD1"
CHECK_FILE "/abc/SAa"
export MAILTO="abc@xyz.com"
export CONTENT="/home/abc/LOG/HC.log"
export SUBJECT="check for files Generated Today"
(
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo "Content-Type: text/html"
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
 echo '<HTML><BODY><PRE>'
 cat $CONTENT
echo '</PRE></BODY></HTML>'
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO

  code here
```

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by multiple location?

Comment: I want to check for the file abc.RIG in serveral folders

Comment: In location /abc/xyz I have many files among them I want the selected 5 files to check whether the file has created today or not and save them in log

Answer (score 0):

```
function CHECK_FILE(){
    cd ${1}
    WRITE_LOG "Checking files in ${1}"  
    FILE=`find . -type f -name "abc.RIG"`

    for OUTPUT in $FILE
    do 
        ls -l $OUTPUT | grep -q "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d").*RIG*"
        if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
        then
            WRITE_LOG "File created for today"
        else
            WRITE_LOG "File not created. please check"
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: Thanks , among multiple files I want to check for only these 5 files(abc.txt, xyz.txt, pqt.txt,gty.txt, pr.RIG) in same location how can I do it above code.

Comment: I want to search for only these 5 files(abc.txt, xyz.RIG, pqt.txt,gty.txt, pr.RIG) created today and print created or not